# PERL How can group strings not in the same line

Tags: perl

Inside text file

```
Letter A = "AAA"
Letter B = "BBB"
```

I try:

```
perl -p -e 's/(Letter A \=)(.*\")(\n+)(Letter B \=)/$1$2$3$4/g' text
```

But it doesn't work. The problem seems to be after `\n`.

Any idea?

Actually I want to exchange the words, how can we do that?
From:
Letter A = "AAA"
Letter B = "BBB"
To:
Letter A = "BBB"
Letter B = "AAA"

If there are others words between 2 lines. Any other solutions?

ABCABC
Letter A = "BBB"
Letter B = "AAA"
DSAAS
TRQWTR
Letter C = "DDD"
Letter D = "CCC"
SDAGER
LPITET

Comment: Why you think problem is after \n? do you have an error message? (and yes, the + looks strange, but I don't know anything about perl.)

Comment: The result is:
Letter A = "AAA"
Letter B = "BBB"
Same as original

Comment: Your revised version takes the trailing newline into `$3` but does not include `$3` in the substitution, which means it is removed from the output.

Answer (score 6):

`-p` splits the input into lines, which means your pattern will never see a `\n` anywhere but at the end of the text it is looking at.  If you want to do multiline matching, you will need to write an actual script or change the input record separator so that it is not split on lines (perhaps `-0777` to use "slurp" mode).

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's/(Letter A =)(.*")(\n+)(Letter B =)/$1 Hello$2$3$4 Hello/' test2
Letter A = Hello "AAA"
Letter B = Hello "BBB"
```

Comment: If I do it that way, it works.
perl -p -e 's/(Letter A \=)(.*\")(\n+)/$1$2/g' test2
Letter A = "AAA"Letter B = "BBB"

Comment: And?  Perhaps you should also mention what you expect to happen; all your regexes simply copy the input to the output unchanged.

Comment: I want to add some words between them.
From
Letter A = "AAA"
Letter B = "BBB"
To
Letter A = "AAA" Hello
Letter B = Hello "BBB"

Comment: Then perhaps you should add the words in the substitution part (where the `$1$2...` are).

Comment: We're back to the original issue I mentioned:  unless you change the input separator, you will only ever see one line at a time.  In particular, your pattern with the `\n` in the middle can never match because the `\n` is always at the end of the line; the `Letter B` part is on the next line, which the script has not yet read.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it into a small program you could do something like this. The commented out part at the top shows that it would work for more than one pair of lines. The way I built it you'd have to pipe the text file in, though.

```
# my $text = qq~Letter A = "AAA"
# Letter B = "BBB"
# Letter C = "CCC"
# Letter D = "DDD"~;
# 
# my @temp = split /\n/, $text;
my @temp = <>;

for (my $i=0; $i <= $#temp; $i+=2) {
  $temp[$i] =~ m/"(\w+)"/;
  my $w1 = $1;
  $temp[$i+1] =~ s/"(\w+)"/"$w1"/;
  my $w2 = $1;
  $temp[$i] =~ s/"$w1"/"$w2"/;
}
print join "\n", @temp;
```

Output:

```
Letter A = "BBB"
Letter B = "AAA"
Letter C = "DDD"
Letter D = "CCC"
```

This is what the code would have to look like if there can be other lines in between.

```
my $text = qq~Letter A = "AAA"
testtesttest
Letter B = "BBB"
loads 
of text
Letter C = "CCC"
Letter D = "DDD"
Letter E = "EEE"

Letter F = "FFF"~;

my @temp = split /\n/, $text;
# my @temp = <>;

my $last_index; # use this to remember where the last 'fist line' was
for (my $i=0; $i <= $#temp; $i+=1) {
  if (!defined $last_index) {
    # if we have not find a 'first line' yet, look if this is it
    $last_index = $i if $temp[$i] =~ m/"(\w+)"/;
  } elsif ($temp[$i] =~ m/"(\w+)"/) {
    # otherwhise if we already have a 'first line', check if this is a 'second line'
    $temp[$last_index] =~ m/"(\w+)"/; # use the 'first line'
    my $w1 = $1; 
    $temp[$i] =~ s/"(\w+)"/"$w1"/; # and the current line
    my $w2 = $1;
    $temp[$last_index] =~ s/"$w1"/"$w2"/;
    $last_index = undef; # remember to reset the 'first line'
  }
}
print join "\n", @temp;
```

Output:

```
Letter A = "BBB"
testtesttest
Letter B = "AAA"
loads 
of text
Letter C = "DDD"
Letter D = "CCC"
Letter E = "FFF"

Letter F = "EEE"
```

Comment: If there are others words between 2 lines, they won't works

ABCABC
Letter A = "BBB"
Letter B = "AAA"
DSAAS
TRQWTR
Letter C = "DDD"
Letter D = "CCC"
SDAGER
LPITET

Comment: @RadekChan could you please add ``\n`` to your example. I don't understand what you mean. Or maybe I do. Since you didn't say about the file containing anything else, I left that out. You'd have to not use ``$i`` and ``$i+1`` but have a variable outside the loop remember the index of the first of two occurences and use that instead of ``$i`` and ``$i`` instead of ``$i+1``. That way you'd switch out a pair of these lines even if there's a bunch of other stuff in between.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this. Try it

`perl -pe 's/$\\n/Hello/g' filename`

**Output**

```
[tethomas@~/Perl]cat t
Letter A = "AAA"
Letter B = "BBB"
[tethomas@~/Perl]perl -pe 's/$\\n/Hello/g' t
Letter A = "AAA"HelloLetter B = "BBB"Hello
```

Comment: Actually I want to exchange the words, how can we do that?
From:
Letter A = "AAA"
Letter B = "BBB"
To:
Letter A = "BBB"
Letter B = "AAA"